# how to place the submenu bootstrap to the left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this menu http://jsbin.com/waxuj/1 and I can't put the submenu to the left neither the arrow of the submenu "Administración"

At the end of the CSS tab, you have the rules of the submenu

```
  /*****************************************/
/*****************************************/
/*****************************************/

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F4F4F4;
border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
    /*right: inherit;*/

  }
}
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: -160px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Somebody can help me?

You can edit at: http://jsbin.com/waxuj/1/edit/

Thanks people!

Comment: To change some floats, positions of the submenu, top, left, nothing

Comment: I have a problema with this--> .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {right:0px;left:auto;}  but I'm trying to change at bootstrap-theme.css, I don't want to change bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like `<li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">`

Comment: i want put the submenu on the left of it parent. In your demo is like mine

Comment: You can use something like <li class="dropdown-submenu pull-left">. "pull-left" class would be the easiest solution.